# Can't display one slide at a time

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm implementing a slider where I like to display one slide at a time.
I've tried it using flexbox for the display container but unfortunately can't make it. How can I display only one slide at a time?

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="contentCard"> 
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Marvell_Logo.svg"  />
    </div>
    <div class="contentCard"> 
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Marvell_Logo.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="contentCard"> 
       <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Marvell_Logo.svg" />
    </div>

  <button class="prev-next-btn prev"></button>
  <button class="prev-next-btn next"></button>
</div>
```

*** CSS ***

```
.viewport {
   display: flex;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}

.prev-next-btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: green;
  top: 35%;
}

.prev-next-btn.next {
  right: 30px;
}

.prev-next-btn.prev {
  left: 30px;
}

.contentCard {
  width: 100%
}
```

[Link to the code](https://codepen.io/Giulia_Marla/pen/zYdPbOO)

Comment: There's no actual procedural code there (in neither your example here or on codepen) that would control the display/hide of each slide so it's expected that it wouldn't do what you intend. Unfortunately the css classes you added for next/previous have nothing built-in to magically perform the operations you may be expecting. I'd suggest maybe looking at one of the numerous tutorials out on the web for this sort of experience.

Comment: @Chris W. Thank you! I got an idea. I will make all slides display: none. Then I will add a new class to the active item to make it block. I guess it should work.

Comment: yep that's generally one of the methods, come on back if you get stuck in an attempt, we've all been there, and like I said there's lots of [basic tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) out there to get the creative juices flowing. Cheers